# "On Friday..." __ "play/plays" or "are going to play"

Tags: grammar, future-tense

In this sentence:

> On Friday I’m going to a concert with some friends. Two local punk bands _____ – they’re quite good.

Can I write "play" or is it "are going to play"?
And in this sentence:

> On Saturday my basketball team _____ an away match.

Can I write "plays" or is it "are going to play"?
Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to refer to the future in English. However, one of the sentences you suggest is clearly incorrect: you definitely should not use the "simple present" *play* in the first sentence. It sounds completely unacceptable to me:

- > On Friday I’m going to a concert with some friends. *Two local punk bands ***play*** [incorrect] – they’re quite good.

The simple present is more acceptable in the second sentence than the first, but nonetheless I don't think it would be a good choice in general, only in certain specific circumstances that I can't quite pin down.

- > On Saturday my basketball team ***plays*** [possible but I don't recommend it] an away match.

  (I would use singular verb agreement with the [collective noun *team*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275493), but some other speakers would use plural verb agreement. Either is considered acceptable.)

---

One option for referring to the future that you haven't mentioned and that I think would be a good choice here is the progressive. I think both of the following sentences sound quite natural:

- > On Friday I’m going to a concert with some friends. Two local punk bands ***are playing*** – they’re quite good.
- > On Saturday my basketball team ***is playing*** an away match.

The present progressive can often be used like this when you have a phrase like "on Friday/on Saturday" that indicates the time in the future when the event is going to occur.

The "be going to" construction that you mentioned also sounds fine to me here:

- > On Friday I’m going to a concert with some friends. Two local punk bands ***are going to play*** – they’re quite good.
- > On Saturday my basketball team ***is going to play*** an away match.

---

It's also possible to combine the progressive with the future marker "will", as in the following example:

- > On Friday I’m going to a concert with some friends. Two local punk bands **will be playing** – they’re quite good.

For some reason, this doesn't sound as good to me in the second sentence.